# Sorting latin strings in Clojure

Tags: sorting, clojure

I did this experiment in the REPL:

```
(sort ["maa" "ácw" "ijl" "aez" "jkl"])
```

I got this:

```
("aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa" "ácw")
```

The right answer is this:

```
("ácw" "aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa")
```

Is there a way to sort Latin strings in Clojure natively? If not why not?

Look I didn't ask how to sort this, I know I can pass the seq through a pipe and substitute the non ANSI chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Collator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) class, on the REPL:

```
=> (import java.util.Locale)
java.util.Locale
=> (import java.text.Collator)
java.text.Collator
=> (def collator (Collator/getInstance (Locale. "pt_BR")))
#'user/collator
=> (sort collator ["maa" "ácw" "ijl" "aez" "jkl"])
("ácw" "aez" "ijl" "jkl" "maa")
```

In this example I'm using the Brazilian [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html). You need to change this locale to the one you want to use. There is a list of supported locales [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/javase7locales-334809.html).

Comment: If your collection to be sorted is big or performances an issue, you can use [CollationKey](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/CollationKey.html), which shall have better performances than `Collator`. It needs more java interop and some type hinting, though.